# How do i write ħ in LaTeX, for the reduced Planck constant?

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)

How do I write the symbol h cross in LaTeX. `$h cross = \frac{h}{2\pi}$` where `$h$` is the plancks constant. I want the h with a line across the vertical bit. I searched the internet but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Ohh. Got it. It is just `$\hbar$`.

Comment: I prefer `$\hslash$`, from the `amssymb` package.