# How can I write a bold version of the reduced Planck constant, `\hbar`?

Tags: fonts, bold

I've tried `\mathbf{\hbar}`, `\boldmath{\hbar}`, and `\boldsymbol{\hbar}`, but none of them produce a bold version of the symbol.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Possible duplicate of [How do i write ħ in LaTeX, for the reduced Planck constant?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62274/how-do-i-write-%c4%a7-in-latex-for-the-reduced-planck-constant). Those seem to work for me.  Can you post a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that reproduces the problem.

Comment: It depends on the fonts you are using. Without an MWE no one can help you

Answer (score 4):

I guess you did the wrong attempts, because `\boldsymbol` works. However, it's better `\bm` (needs the `bm` package to be loaded *after* `amsmath`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$\hbar\ne\bm{\hbar}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you are using Times based fonts with `\usepackage{mathptmx}`, then *no* attempt can be successful, because the package doesn't support bold math symbols. If that's the case, do

```
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
```

instead of `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.

Comment: Thanks, the \includepackage{bm} worked. Trying \usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} led me down a long dark path that I finally abandoned.